# ASP.NET MVC Display Format does not format DateTime to just Date string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, metadata, string-formatting

I've got my display format setup as so

```
<DisplayName("birthdate")> _
<DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")> _
Public Property BirthDate As DateTime
```

Then in the View I have the following

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.BirthDate, Model.BirthDate)%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.BirthDate) %>
```

Meaning that the output "should" be

> 6/24/1982

But unfortunately, the output is

> 6/24/1982 12:00:00 AM

Does anyone know what I might be missing here?

Comment: I don't know the VB.NET lambda syntax but I think the second param in your TextBoxFor might be surplus - it might be interpreting that as the HTML attributes object. However that won't cause your problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digging through the MVC2 source from Codeplex, my best guess is that you need to use `EditorFor` not `TextBoxFor`. TextBoxFor uses

```
string valueParameter = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

ignoring the format attributes (although it did look them up through the ModelMetadata classes) whereas EditorFor and DisplayFor are built on the internal TemplateHelpers which do use the format attributes.